How to join the URL after changing the query using python requests
After URL.replace URL has been divided into two parts. Replaced query has been in text format, hence it's not a proper URL. I would like to fix it.
As it's an invalid UTL got 404 error:

ERROR: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:  'https://www.example.com?param=specialanother**[]=char'**

My code:
  import requests
  url = 'https://www.example.com?param=specialanother[]=char'
  url = requote_uri(urlunparse([scheme, netloc, path, None, query, fragment]))
  url = url.replace("%5B", "[").replace("%5D", "]")
  self.url = "".join(url)


Note: []=char part is in text not part of URL..


what is requote_uri?

Encodes a wider range of special characters.

there's nothing in your code that can divide in two parts your url except requote_uri. that's why i'm asking you to show the code of that function and not what you think it does.

looks like it's failed yes. show the code. and replace works the other way around url.replace("[", "%5B").replace("]", "%5D")

Looks like it's failed to add a two strings in that URL. After [] it's failed to add it to the url that is causing the issue. I have tried in general too test1 = "https://www.example.com?param=specialanother?"
test2 = "[]=char"
url = test1 + test2
print(url)

[edit] your question and add the code of requote_uri

You can use the urllib.parse module for parsing and reconstructing URLs. This ensures that the URL remains valid and properly encoded.
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, parse_qs, urlencode
    
url = 'https://www.example.com?param=specialanother[]=char'
parsed_url = urlparse(url) # parses the URL
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query) # converts the query string into a dictionary
query_params['param'] = '<new_param>' # update your param
new_query = urlencode(query_params, doseq=True) # converts the dictionary back into a properly encoded query string.
new_url = urlunparse((parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.netloc, parsed_url.path, parsed_url.params, new_query, parsed_url.fragment)) # reconstruct the full URL
print(new_url)

Output:
> https://www.example.com?param=%3Cnew_param%3E


my case I don't need to change any query parameters all I have done it [] in query I have replaced the entire URL. after that changed part considered as string now I would like to have a URL after the replace..

Don't understand. Your question is unclear, please update the question accordingly.

My question is I am using python requests.. I have a URL and contains [] when I execute the script [] are encoding with %5B%5D in the URL hence URL is invalid.
